# Can I claim my migrated answer?

Tags: support, answers, migration

I found this scenario interesting, so I thought I'd ask.

I answered a question posted on the webapps site: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9922/free-asp-net-ms-access-support-webhosting-closed

I checked back in a short time later and noticed that the question was closed, my answer deleted, and the question migrated to the webmasters site: [Free ASP.NET & MS Access support webhosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6203/free-asp-net-ms-access-support-webhosting)

The question on the new site had my name in the answer, but no link to the profile (I'm assuming it was treated as an anonymous answer). Since I had never been to the site before, I went ahead and logged in, linking up my S[OFUM] profile to the account.

Now that I'm registered, is there any way to "claim" this answer? I'm not too worried if I can or cannot claim the answer, but I'm wondering how often this is occurring now with the ever expanding and migrating of sites/questions/answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a very similar situation I was advised to flag the post for moderator attention and request that it be linked to my new account.

Comment: I've gone ahead and flagged it, we'll see what happens...

Comment: Diamond moderators can't actually do anything in this situation. You might be better off emailing team@stackexchange.com with the details.

Comment: Yes, but I was advised by a Dev to flag it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think this should be linked automatically when you create a user by linking to your other accout where the post was originated from. Technically, it would be no big issue I think, and even if it is some advanced queries to be performed, it should be possible - specially since this would be a thing that happens only once - when you link the accounts.

**EDIT:**
**Arjan** added a comment with a [link](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association) that describe how the creating of new accounts, and linking to existing has improved due to improvements to OpenID by Google. So now this should work automatically!

Thanks to Arjan for pointing to this!

---

And of course, the automatic system may fail, and if so happens, you would have to flag the post for moderator attention and request that it be linked to your new account as **Al Everett** said in the answer you accepted.

Comment: It usually is automatically linked, that's what happens in most migration scenarios. There are times when it fails, however, which is when you need to flag for attention.

Comment: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association/

Comment: (Though I don't know how that works for *answers*...)