# Migrated question/answer not assigned to any user despite the fact the account exists and is linked to the account on the original site

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, migration, association

There's [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9984/is-aerial-view-officially-gone-from-maps-in-microsofts-bing/9985#9985) on a Web Apps question migrated from Super User.

The poster has an account on Web Apps which is associated with his Super User account, but as you can see the answer hasn't been associated with his account.

Is there anything a moderator can do or is this something a dev has to do?

[Brian Ojeda's Web Apps profile](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/6977/brian-ojeda)

[Brian Ojeda'a Super User profile](https://superuser.com/users/20433/brian-ojeda)

**UPDATE**

Given that it is something that a dev has to do (see Marc's comment) there's two further things that this highlights:

1. Do we need an easier way of flagging this sort of thing to the development team other than e-mail or raising a question on (a) Meta?
2. Why does there *seem* to be an increase in the number of questions and answers that don't get relinked to their owners after migration.

**UPDATE 2**

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/218939/my-computer-icon-on-desktop-displays-wrong) on Super User demonstrates the problem as well. The question's been migrated, the user has linked accounts, but the question isn't owned by anyone.

Here's <strike>another of this same situation [posted here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71358/can-i-claim-my-migrated-answer).</strike> (Appears okay now) And [one more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71633/how-should-newbies-ask-sql-questions).

Comment: No, moderators can't do this.

Comment: @Marc - well in that case can I request that a dev looks into it. We're getting an increasing number of these on Webapps.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I've seen several requests that deal with this.  It seems like this could be an issue rather than just a one-off thing.

Comment: @Marc - I'm with @Rebecca on this. There's the issue of the existing posts not being linked to the correct accounts *and* the issue of why this is happening in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recently changed how these unassociated posts are searched for, using an http call that sometimes times out.  A retry mechanism sounds like a good idea.

*Back to the refactoring board.*

Comment: Is this an ongoing process so that if a user creates an account much later they'll still regain ownership of the question?

Comment: @ChrisF yes, that's exactly the use case this process was designed for; it just has a bit of intrinsic failure common to http that we need to fix.

Comment: We've got another flag on WA regarding [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/photosynth-has-turned-from-a-3d-photo-app-to-a-panorama-sharing-website/10156#10156) and the lack of association.

Comment: @Rebecca - he hadn't associated his SU and WA accounts when the post was flagged. I notice that he has now. It might take a while for this process to cycle round and perform the association.