# How should newbies ask SQL questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, asking-questions

We often see poorly asked questions relating to SQL that don't inspire us to help or answer because they are so poorly phrased and missing critical information.  What do you look for in a good question about SQL that encourages you to spend your valuable time answering questions?

Instead of us rehashing time and again in each poorly phrased question why we might not help, we could point questioners to the answers below.

Comment: *(1)* This question belongs on meta, not the main stackoverflow site. *(2)* These concerns aren't specific to SQL: there are poor questions in almost every category.

Comment: Oh err.  I didn't know about the meta site.  Thanks for moving the question.

Comment: Sorry couldn't avoid the obvious: a poorly placed question complaining about a poorly phrased question.

Comment: Mea culpa. I didn't know about the meta site at the time. Consider me told off.

Answer (score 3):

Including a simple script to reproduce the issue independent of their particular database would be extremely helpful - as would stating the flavour of SQL (i.e. DBMS), and clear intended results.

Comment: +1 for the flavour (yummy ;)) - people assume their flavour is The One True SQL (most common with the MSSQL and MySQL crowds), and then are surprised that their platform-specific solutions won't work with SQLite, Oracle or Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

1. Describe your schema with some simple create table statements.  Don't include columns that aren't relevant to the question.
2. Tell us what you've seen in an *explain plan*.  If you don't know what this means it's worth finding out more about your execution plans for your databases and how to interpret the *explain plan* command for your database.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if all questioners:

1. Describe what they're trying to achieve (i.e. the "why")
2. Describe what they've tried so far (including any output or error messages)
3. Describe what they expected to get (e.g. example query results)

I guess this is not specific to SQL...