# Account is not linked after question migration even though the user has already registered on target site

Tags: bug, migration, user-accounts, linked-accounts, association

There was [a question posted on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/266862/revisions) which was migrated to [Meta Android.SE](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2019/no-matching-tag). As of current writing, the OP's username is greyed (no user profile).

However, when I checked the account, they have registered both on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/300981/schwertspize) and [Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/120030/schwertspize).

This issue seems to be the same as [Migrated question/answer not assigned to any user despite the fact the account exists and is linked to the account on the original site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71519/migrated-question-answer-not-assigned-to-any-user-despite-the-fact-the-account-e), but it's posted 5 years ago and already got [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), so I doubt if this is the same case. If there's a difference, then I think it's that the user never went to Meta Android.SE before (but I can't confirm).

Comment: On that old bug report one of the devs says it is batch process that needs to run and that might take a while. Timeframes on SE are normally 6 to 8 weeks....